# Git does not properly detect modification of certain files?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, dvcs, code-composer

I've noticed that Git does not properly detect modified .out files (which are already in the index) generated by TI's Code Composer Studio (Eclipse). After compiling/building, calling `git status` shows .out files under `changes to be committed` (as deleted) and `untracked files` instead of in `changes not staged for commit`. Any idea what specifically causes certain files to end up like this?

Comment: Are the file names the same? Could it be the IDE actually deletes one file, and creates another one?

Comment: @kabanus The filenames are the same. The IDE does explicitly delete them first, though. So while it's building, the file doesn't exist. I would assume this isn't a problem though because the raw .bin files that are also generated go through the same process but are properly detected as modified files by Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with GIT. By design, this is how it works. I ran a test to double check but if:

1. A file `file.out` is part of the tree
2. Something/one runs `git rm file.out`. It has to be a `git rm`, if the deletion is not staged this won't reproduce.
3. You create a file of the same name. It will be listed as untracked.

This is standard GIT behavior. Staged changes are "almost" committed, and just like re-creating a file previously deleted in a different commit will be listed as new, so it will happen here. Note if the deletion is not staged, then what you expect as the right behavior will occur - `git` will know it is the same file.

To have `git` understand the files are the same, you need to run

4. `git add file.out`

so `git` sees the same file still exists in the stage area, and just lists a single `modified` staged to commit. The reason it works like this is to have an extra half committed layer you can still play around and reset to (like a checkpoint in a game).

As to **why** Composer does this I am not sure. I think the right behavior is staging all file changes, so I do not know why the new file is not added to the tree. If this is just a log output that is not part of the source consider adding `*.out` to `.gitignore`, though you have to make sure Composer is not adding it (and bypassing the ignore).

Answer (score 0):

A file's status is "deleted" if it exists in the current commit but not in the index.

A file is untracked if it exists in the work-tree but is not in the index.

In this case, both are true: the file is in the current commit (frozen there forever, along with all the other frozen-into-the-commit files), *not* in the index (because someone or something removed it from the index), and *is* in the work-tree.  Given your description in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52671712/git-does-not-properly-detect-modification-of-certain-files#comment92273587_52671712), the IDE may have either run `git rm` to remove the file from both the index and work-tree, or may have run the equivalent of `git add -u` after deleting the file from the work-tree but before re-creating the file in the work-tree.

(The `git add` command, noticing that the file is missing from the work-tree, will *remove* the file from the index.  A subsequent `git add`, run when the file *is* in the work-tree, will copy it into the index, but you'll need a variant of `git add` that adds a file that is not already present in the index.)